# scatter plot filter legend on zoom

Tags: highcharts

I have a scatter plot.. i would like to filter the series legend when a zoom-in operation is performed .. So the series whose datapoints fall into the zoom area should only appear in the legend. this should reset when the reset zoom button is clicked.I started to try here on this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ps1myxtk/ but do not know if there is a setting to achieve it

```
zoomType: 'xy
```

Is there a setting somewhere to achieve this ?

Also I have 4 quadrants in the background.. i would like to zoom into the quadrant. Whats the best way to achieve it? Should I use drilldown on quadrant? Instead of area series as quadrant, can I use a stacked-column series as quadrant.. enable datalabels and do a drill down when the datalabels are clicked? Like here http://jsfiddle.net/ps1myxtk/1/ (Bdw, why is the 0.5 label not aligned in the middle here?)

Or should I continue with area series create a SVG labels for each quadrant and clicking on it perform a filtering operation similar to what i expect when zoom is performed?

I have another fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/ps1myxtk/3/ but drildown/zoom-in with legend filtering i am not able to do

There is a lot of flexibility which is overwhelming sometimes.. Could some expert please help me and create an fiddle example with best technique to achieve the goal? The idea is to use what is already available and not re-invent and write unnecessary functionality

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `redraw` event you can loop through the points and check `isInside` property.  Depending on the result, you can set some custom flag on a series, run `legend.update()` and remove specified series in `afterGetAllItems` event function:

```
(function(H) {
    H.addEvent(H.Legend, 'afterGetAllItems', function(e) {
        var allItems = e.allItems,
            index = allItems.length - 1;

        if (this.chart.rendered) {
            while (index > -1) {
                if (!allItems[index].isInVisibleRange) {
                    H.erase(allItems, allItems[index]);
                }
                index--;
            }
        }
    });
}(Highcharts));



Highcharts.chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'scatter',
        zoomType: 'xy',
        events: {
            redraw: function() {
                var series = this.series;
                this.rendered = true;

                if (allowChartUpdate) {
                    allowChartUpdate = false;

                    if (this.resetZoomButton) {
                        series.forEach(function(s) {
                            s.isInVisibleRange = false;

                            s.points.forEach(function(p) {
                                if (p.isInside) {
                                    s.isInVisibleRange = true;
                                }
                            });
                        });

                    } else {
                        series.forEach(function(s) {
                            s.isInVisibleRange = true;
                        });
                    }

                    this.legend.update({});
                }

                allowChartUpdate = true;
            }
        }
    },

    ...
});
```

---

To zoom to some quadrant use `setExtremes` method:

```
document.getElementById('zoom').addEventListener('click', function() {
    chart.showResetZoom();
    chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(0.5, 1, false);
    chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(0.5, 1);
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fh614gkv/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts

Comment: thanks a lot.. you guys are awesome.. I spend whole day playing in fiddle and checking highchart configs and then you come up with a solution which is unprecedented .. really awesome.. Thanks a lot

Comment: the solution you provided is messing up the dataLabels rendering.. http://jsfiddle.net/b53vmyrq/ click the toggle dataLabels button ..

Comment: Hi @user4772933, Yes, but what is the problem with dataLabels?

Comment: I thin it is redoing the animation and somehow the dataLabels are coming from below. Cleck the ToggleDataLabels .The normal datalabel toggle experience is like this  http://jsfiddle.net/z0m6upx5/ , When i disable you solution I get the default behavior. Could you please fix your solution? It would be very helpful to me

Comment: Hi @user4772933, With adding `dataLabels` by `chart.update` things are getting complicated because another `redraw` event is fired. Please check this attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7s5akLrg/